# Why hydrofluoric acid (HF) has two Raman bands?

Tags: vibrations, raman-spectroscopy

Hydrofluoric acid (HF) is a diatomic molecule with only one vibrational coordinate. Therefore I would expect only one Raman band, however there are two. Why?

[image][image]([source](http://www.process-instruments-inc.com/pages/acid.html))

Answer (score 1):

The spectra you show are of aqueous HF i.e. a solution of HF in water. In these conditions HF is strongly hydrogen bonded to the water and other HF molecules so you are not taking the spectrum of a individual isolated HF molecule.

I would guess the big peak is the vibration of the HF bond and will be roughly the same as the frequency of the vibration in the vapour phase. The smaller band will be a dimer (HF)$_2$ or possibly HF.H$_2$O.

You would probably get a better answer on the [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).